# How do I print the mysqli result of SUM() with PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table called "hours", with the following columns:

id, int(11)

date, date

hours, int(11)

I'm running this query on the table:

```
SELECT SUM(hours) as value_total FROM hours
```

Which returns the correct sum of the values in the hours column - 68586

The result of this gets passed to an array, however when I try to print the index of the array that contains the sum 68586, it does not appear on the screen.

Here is my code in PHP

```
if($result = $conn->query("SELECT SUM(hours) as value_total FROM hours") or die(mysql_error())) {
    if ($result->num_rows) {

        while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
        echo '<pre>', print_r($rows), '</pre>';

        print_r($rows['value_total']);
    } 
} else {
    die($conn->error);
}
```

the print_r was an attempt to print the index of the sum amount passed to the array but there is no output from it :(

right now, what's on my screen is :

```
Array
(
    [value_total] => 68586
)
1
```

This is honestly a noob mistake I'm making somewhere I know it, but how do I print the "value_total" to the page with php?

Comment: This is why you should always use braces for control structures like `while`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

To understand your mistake, change:

```
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
echo '<pre>', print_r($rows), '</pre>';
print_r($rows['value_total']);
```

to:

```
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<pre>', print_r($rows), '</pre>';
    print_r($rows['value_total']);
}
```

as your `print_r` is outside of the while loop because only the immediate next command is part of the loop and is $rows actually `null` on the second line.

However as @Phil has pointed out, If you're expecting a single row result, don't bother with the while loop...

```
if( $rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  echo '<pre>', print_r($rows), '</pre>';
  print_r($rows['value_total']);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with a `while` loop. That query is guaranteed one result

Comment: I freaking love you guys ! It was the brackets heh.. I upvoted your comment but I guess it doesn't show since I'm not cool enough yet.

Comment: As for the while loop, I should have known better